# Please change the "hyperlink" symbol in the editor

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

My goodness, for those of us who are not hip, please put text under the infinity symbol that apparently means 'link'.  Not intuitive at all.  Tooltips are nice, but text is nicer.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the toolbox on the page where you enter your questions/answers?

Comment: Yes.  Not a huge deal I guess, but still, the rest of the stack sites have differing but consistently recognizable icon work. ( text is the best icon though)

Comment: +1, the link icon is not intuitive at all.

Comment: I've grown accustomed to entering the markdown for Links and Images as I type, though I agree this was a rough "discovery" item when AU first launched.

Comment: Oooh I can do Ctrl+L as a shortcut! I like keyboard shortcuts....

Comment: I also don't think the other symbols, Blockquote and Code, are particularly intuitive.

Comment: Ctrl-L is hyperlink shortcut? OLE!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one take I've been working on.

[image]

It's a bit big, so I ended up scaling it down a little and included it in this mock up.

[image]

This thing is still monstrous. So I'll continue to work and hopefully refine this idea. I've included the two SVG ([simple](http://ubuntuone.com/p/TNA/) and "[detailed](http://ubuntuone.com/p/TNB/)") if anyone wants a starting base.

After some more manipulation.

[image]

[image]

[SVG Source](http://ubuntuone.com/p/TNL/) Regular: (#333333) Hover: (#DD4C00)

Comment: Nice!  That's all it takes, now I look and see "Bold, Italic, Link, quote,(wtf) , img"  But that's ok, context can be measured by aggregation, <$> must be code, because that goes with hyperlinks, blockquotes and image tags in a gui for webpage comments.

Comment: Marco, great! i'll put it in the sprite in the next few days.

Comment: @Jin Thank you very much! I've been between keeping and dropping the underline - so I'll leave that up to you. I think the simplicity of "no underline" works better with the current icon set.

Comment: How about just an image of `<a>` with an underline.  I know it's kind of nerdy, but this is a nerdy place, and many people will recognize it.

Comment: @Marco: Good job; the bigger version is easier to identify, though. Perhaps try rotating it so it runs diagonally? I might give it a try if I get the time.

Comment: @Marco I have updated the image sprite with your version. it will be in the next deployment.

Comment: @Jin It looks great (I'm biased) thanks!

Answer (score 4):

*This isn't an answer, but an observation of other "Popular" tools implementation of "Hyperlink" icon*

## OpenOffice 3

[image]

## Microsoft Office Word 2000-2007

[image]

## Google Docs

[image]

Our icon should implement two of the three options.

- Blank Page
- Globe/World
- Chain Link

Doing any two combination of three in mono-chrome should improve the current "Infinity" look of the icon.

Answer (score 2):

I actually thought this wasn't even possible. I simply resorted to doing my hyperlinks manually and I didn't care enough to check what the infinity symbol meant.